# Adding function/else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to add a function to this code for conversion to Kelvin, it seems as though I can't do it. The Celsius to Fahrenheit works fine, i thought I'd start simple just specify the Fahrenheit to Kelvin.

```js
function convert(degree) {
  var x;
  if (degree == "C") {
    x = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
  } else {
    x = (document.getElementById("f").value - 32) * 5 / 9;
    document.getElementById("c").value = Math.round(x);
  } else if {
    x = (document.getElementById("f").value - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
    document.getElementById("k").value = Math.round(x);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Celcius to Fahrenhet</h2>

  <p>Insert a number into one of the input fields below:</p>

  <p><input id="c" onkeyup="convert('C')"> degrees Celsius</p>

  <p><input id="f" onkeyup="convert('F')"> degrees Fahrenheit</p>

  <p><input id="k" onkeyup="convert('K')"> degrees Kelvin</p>

  <p>Note that the <b>Math.round()</b> method is used, so that the result will be returned as an integer.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Aesthetically everything is the same but function is lost when i add 'else' for Kelvin

Comment: your if/else structure should be:  if/else if/else

Comment: Give your inputs a type, `<input type="number" ... />`

Answer (score 0):

Your if/else structure is wrong, it should look similar to this:

```
function convert(degree) {
      if (degree === 'C') {
        let x = (document.getElementById('c').value * 9) / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById('f').value = Math.round(x);
      } else if (degree === 'F') {
        let x = ((document.getElementById('f').value - 32) * 5) / 9;
        document.getElementById('c').value = Math.round(x);
      } else {
        let x = ((document.getElementById('f').value - 32) * 5) / 9 + 273.15;
        document.getElementById('k').value = Math.round(x);
      }
    }
```

However, with the way you wrote this function, if you type something into the Celsius input it'll show you its Fahrenheit equivalent and vice versa but it won't update the Kelvin input as well. In addition, typing on the Kelvin input before having anything on the Fahrenheit input won't work properly because it'll use an empty value `""` for the calculation.

This could be one of the possible solutions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>JavaScript Celcius to Fahrenhet</h2>

    <p>Insert a number into one of the input fields below:</p>

    <p><input id="c" onkeyup="convert('C')" /> degrees Celsius</p>

    <p><input id="f" onkeyup="convert('F')" /> degrees Fahrenheit</p>

    <p><input id="k" onkeyup="convert('K')" /> degrees Kelvin</p>

    <p>Note that the <b>Math.round()</b> method is used, so that the result will be returned as an integer.</p>
  </body>
  <script>
    function convert(degree) {
      if (degree === 'C') {
        document.getElementById('f').value = CelsiusToFahrenheit();
        document.getElementById('k').value = CelsiusToKelvin();
      } else if (degree === 'F') {
        document.getElementById('c').value = FahrenheitToCelsius();
        document.getElementById('k').value = FahrenheitToKelvin();
      } else {
        document.getElementById('f').value = KelvinToFahrenheit();
        document.getElementById('c').value = KelvinToCelsius();
      }
    }

    function CelsiusToFahrenheit() {
      const celsius = Number(document.getElementById('c').value);
      return Math.round((celsius * 9) / 5 + 32);
    }

    function CelsiusToKelvin() {
      const celsius = Number(document.getElementById('c').value);
      return Math.round(celsius + 273.15);
    }

    function FahrenheitToCelsius() {
      const fahrenheit = Number(document.getElementById('f').value);
      return Math.round(((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9);
    }

    function FahrenheitToKelvin() {
      const fahrenheit = Number(document.getElementById('f').value);
      return Math.round(((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9 + 273.15);
    }

    function KelvinToCelsius() {
      const kelvin = Number(document.getElementById('k').value);
      return Math.round(kelvin - 273.15);
    }

    function KelvinToFahrenheit() {
      const kelvin = Number(document.getElementById('k').value);
      return Math.round(((kelvin - 273.15) * 9) / 5 + 32);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

What i did was create a bunch of helper functions to that just handle the math to convert from one measurement to another while also converting the input value to a number with `Number()` otherwise whenever the first operation that uses the input is an addition, javascript will just concatenate the values because the input value comes as a string, resulting in something like

```
"2" + 1
// "21"
```

With the extra functions we keep `convert(degree)` clean and let it only worry about updating the fields while the other functions do the calculations. This way it's also easier to update the other two fields by just calling the corresponding function inside `convert(degree)` and assigning its returning value to the corresponding input.

Comment: Those inputs need types. `<input type="number" ... />`

Comment: Even if you add `type="Number"` to the inputs their values will still be a string, look at this [example](https://codepen.io/deafening_roar/pen/KKPzWWz).

Comment: An input must have a type.

Comment: Not really. If the type attribute is not present or it contains an invalid value, it will just default to the text type.

Answer (score 0):

Your *if-else* structure isn't syntactically correct.  You can't have `if` without a condition.  Also, you can't have another `else` after an `else` block.  You have to use `else if (something)` on all the blocks except the last one, which can be just `else`.

You have:

```
if (degree == "C") {
} else {
} else if {
}
```

Change to this kind of structure:

```
if (degree == "C") {
  // handle C here
} else if (degree == "F") {
  // handle F here
} else if (degree == "K") {
  // handle K here
} else {
  // throw exception here because of an unsupported value for `degree`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified `if` condition. You just jumped to `else` and then `else if` without condition. Plus, in your original code you don't update all the fields, you just update `C` and `F`.

So what I did:

1. Fix the `if-else` structure.
2. Updated the right values for each degree field.

You just need to update the values of the conversion because I don't know the math behind it.

It should be like this:

```js
function convert(degree) {
  var x;
  if (degree == "C") {
    c_to_f = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(c_to_f);
    c_to_k = 0; //update it
    document.getElementById("k").value = c_to_k;
  } else if (degree == "F") {
    f_to_c = (document.getElementById("f").value - 32) * 5 / 9;
    document.getElementById("c").value = Math.round(f_to_c);
    f_to_k = 0; //update it
    document.getElementById("k").value = f_to_k;
  } else {
    k_to_f = (document.getElementById("k").value - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
    document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(k_to_f);
    k_to_c = 0; //update it
    document.getElementById("c").value = k_to_c;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Celcius to Fahrenhet</h2>

  <p>Insert a number into one of the input fields below:</p>

  <p><input id="c" onkeyup="convert('C')"> degrees Celsius</p>

  <p><input id="f" onkeyup="convert('F')"> degrees Fahrenheit</p>

  <p><input id="k" onkeyup="convert('K')"> degrees Kelvin</p>

  <p>Note that the <b>Math.round()</b> method is used, so that the result will be returned as an integer.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch case to avoid multiple if/else. The code will be better and less confusing as well if you avoid multiple variables `k,K, c,C, f,F`. Descriptive variable names are always better. Give a type to your inputs.

```
function convert(inputId) {
  // You might want to ensure your input is number by changing its type to number.
  const currentValue = document.getElementById(inputId).value; 
  switch (inputId) {
    case 'celsius':
      // do celsius conversion here;
      break;

    case 'fahrenheit':
      // do fahrenheit conversion here;
      break;
    case 'kelvin':
      // do kelvin conversion here;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Celcius to Fahrenhet</h2>

  <p>Insert a number into one of the input fields below:</p>

  <p><input type="number" id="celcius" onkeyup="convert('celcius')"> degrees Celsius</p>

  <p><input type="number" id="fahrenheit" onkeyup="convert('fahrenheit')"> degrees Fahrenheit</p>

  <p><input type="number" id="kelvin" onkeyup="convert('kelvin')"> degrees Kelvin</p>

  <p>Note that the <b>Math.round()</b> method is used, so that the result will be returned as an integer.</p>

</body>

</html>
```